# Extracting specific number of data points from a smooth curve

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I have a dataset `df`, using that I am plotting a scatterplot. Following is the code for it:

```
 g <- ggplot() + theme_bw() +
                geom_point(data = df, aes_string(df[,1], df[,2]), color = 'red')+
                geom_smooth(data = df, aes_string(df[,1], df[,2]),formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, df = input$degree_1), method = "lm", color = "green3", level = 1, size = 0.5)
```

`input$degree_1` is the slider to change the degree of the polynomial fit.

Secondly, I am extracting the data points of the smoothen curve like this:

```
r <- ggplot_build(g)$data[[2]]
```

Now, I want to cut that smoothen curve using two verticle lines and extract the data points of the curve lying in between those two lines:

```
v_f1 <- subset(r, x > input$Vert1 & x < input$Vert2, select = c(x,y))
```

`input$Vert1` and `input$Vert2`are the sliders to change the positions of the verticle lines.

What I want:
I want to be able to control the number of points that are getting subsetted and extracted in the above-mentioned command by those verticle lines.

[image]

For now, it is extracting a random number of points, I want the user to be able to control that. For eg., if I want to cut that profile and extract 100 points in one case and 120 points in another case and so on. Or I could just set a fix number for all the cases.

Comment: Fit the model outside `ggplot` and use `predict`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit?

Comment: @kolas0202 Please clarify also how you want to sample your points. Should they be distributed evenly along x axis (same dx) or along curve (same ds) ?

Comment: `x <- seq(from = ..., to = ..., length.out = ...); fit <- lm(y ~ splines::bs(x, df = input$degree_1), data = df); y <- predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(x = x))`

Comment: @billy34 I want to sample my points such that they should be distributed evenly along the curve i.e. same ds.

Comment: I was fearing this as it's not simple. You have to integrate curve to generate this.I would suggest you then to have a look to package `bezier` by first fitting a bezier curve using `bezierCurveFit` function and then generate points along it using function `pointsOnBezier ` using `evenly_spaced` method.There is one caveat as start and end point (vert1,vert2) must be provided as curvilinear abcsissa (t1 and t2 parameters) ! Roland's tips would be simpler if not perfect according to your needs.